# severe thunderstorms warnings dataset for europe

Tags: data, weather, europe

I'm looking at the possibility of using georef data on historic thunderstorms alerts. Does anyone know of a good (free) source for this information?

Comment: Please See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29810/near-real-time-sources-of-lightning-strike-data